# Is 'round about' a valid formal synonym for 'approximately'?

Tags: word-usage

I'm not a native English speaker and currently proofreading a friend's thesis. She uses the words 'round about' as a synonym for 'approximately', for example:

> The average share of X is round about 45 % and the average share of Y is round about 10 %.

To me, this sounds quite informal, not something you would write in an academic paper, but I might be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you need *roughly X* or *X rounded*. *Approximately* means you don't have the number, only the kinda sorta value.

Comment: For what it’s worth, they did it in this academic paper: [*For our investigated system HxV2O5 ▵n/▵x is round about −0.93 and ▵k/▵x round about 0.15 at the same wavelength.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7953475/)

Comment: Also, if this is what is meant — *The average share of X rounded is about 45% and the average share of Y rounded is about 10%.* — it would mean something different if you changed *round about* to *approximately*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Round about* sounds very informal to me. *Around* would be less informal, and *approximately* would be best for a thesis.